# Error while running linker am using TIVA C TM4C123G and IAR

Tags: arm, clock-speed, launchpad, iar, linker

I am trying to change and read my TM4C123G launchpad clock frequency to 80 MHZ using TIVAWARE libraries so here is my code:

```
#include <lm4f120h5qr.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "driverlib/sysctl.c"
#include "driverlib/pin_map.h"

void main()
{
SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_2_5|SYSCTL_USE_PLL|SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN|SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ);
int x= SysCtlClockGet();
while(1){  }
}
```

I am facing two problems the first problem there is an error while compiling this code the error is:

> Error[Li005]: no definition for "SysCtlDelay" [referenced from C:\Users\ZMK\Documents\TIVA C\IAR\TM4C FREQUENCY\Debug\Obj\main.o]

where SysCtlDelay() is a function and its definition is in the driverlib/sysctl.c included in the top. so I don't know why this is happening!!

the second problem is while debugging the code the local variable X doesn't show a value it only shows an unknown value, I tried to make it volatile but nothing changed too!!

thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't help you with the first issue. I suggest you to visit TI TIVA forum directly [link](http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/tiva_arm/), it's very responsive. Regarding your second problem: just define your variable outside of main(), i.e make it global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for solving first problem, You should:
1. add library files (library.a for IAR) to your project. In Project window -> add group(or files) -> driverlib.a in Driverlib/ewarm folder. (Sorry, I'm using Keil or Eclipse but sure these acts looks same in different IDE)
2. in main.c include driverlib/sysctl.h instead of sysctl.c
Don't understand second issue, can you add your code?